# JSF - range slider with "time" values

Tags: jquery, jsf, time, primefaces, slider

I have JSF webapp with Primefaces 3.5 and i would like to have a range slider but with time values (hour:minute) .. as in this picture

[slider http://img547.imageshack.us/img547/3112/timeslider.jpg](http://img547.imageshack.us/img547/3112/timeslider.jpg)

this is the code for a range slider with integer values :

```
<h:panelGrid columns="1" style="margin-bottom:10px">                    
    <h:outputText id="displayRange" value="Between #{sliderBean.number6} and #{sliderBean.number7}"/>                    
    <p:slider for="txt6,txt7" display="displayRange" style="width:400px" range="true" 
              displayTemplate="Between {min} and {max}"/>
</h:panelGrid>
<h:inputHidden id="txt6" value="#{sliderBean.number6}" />
<h:inputHidden id="txt7" value="#{sliderBean.number7}" />
```

where sliderBean.number6 and sliderBean.number7 are integer..
i think that to do what i want is to redefine the jquery slide function that display the range values and work with "minutes" instead of "hours"..

```
    $(function() {
    $(".slider-range").slider({
        range: true,
        min: 0,
        max: 1440,
        step: 15,
        slide: function(e, ui) {
            var hours = Math.floor(ui.value / 60);
            var minutes = ui.value - (hours * 60);

            if(hours.length == 1) hours = '0' + hours;
            if(minutes.length == 1) minutes = '0' + minutes;

            $('#displayRange').html(hours+':'+minutes);
        }
    });
});
```

but .. honestly.. i don't know how to do.. (and if this is the correct way..)
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have put together a fiddle that uses [jQRangeSlider](http://ghusse.github.io/jQRangeSlider/) and [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/)

http://jsfiddle.net/tPMsv/7/

```
$("#slider").dateRangeSlider({
    bounds: { 
        min: moment().startOf("day").toDate(), 
        max: moment().endOf("day").toDate() 
    },
    defaultValues: { 
        min: moment().startOf("day").add("hours",6).toDate(), 
        max: moment().endOf("day").subtract("hours",6).toDate()
    },
    formatter: function (value) {
        return moment(value).format("HH:mm");
    }
});
```

I'm using momentjs because is a great library to deal with datetime values on javascript, but you don't have to use it if you are familiar with another library or just want to deal with the native functions.

Please let me know if you have any questions.